# React.js event with arrow function vs without any () function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello i am wondering why only normal functions like below works and arrow functions do not.

```
const Form = () =>{

    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    const handle=(e)=>{
       setText(e.target.value);
    }
    const alertText = (e) =>{
       console.log(text);
       alert(text);
    }

    return(
       <>
           <input onChange={handle}></input>
           <button onClick={alertText}>submit</button>
           <h1>{text}</h1>   
       </>
    )}
```

using arrow functions like `<input onChange={()=>handle}>`
doesn't work at all and I have no idea what the difference between of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

component expects onChange as a function, that function will be called when the user changes the value of the input.

**NOTE:** It's syntactically correct but the handle function will not execute.

When you do

```
<input onChange={handle}></input>
// it's equivalent to
<input onChange={(e)=>{ setText(e.target.value); }}></input>
```

But when you do

```
<input onChange={()=>handle}></input>
// it's equivalent to
<input onChange={(e) => ()=>{ setText(e.target.value);}}></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's because if you use an arrow function on the element you have to call it like this:

```
<input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
 <input onChange={(e)=>handle(e)}>
```

You are not passing the event into the handle function

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input onChange={()=>handle}>
```

In above case onChange is assigned a function which has a single statement `handle` inside it. So onclick the statement `handle` is run. nothing happens.

```
 <input onChange={()=>handle()}>
```

In above case onChange is assigned a function which has a single statement `handle()` inside it. So onclick handle is executed.

```
<input onChange={handle}>
```

In above case onChange is assigned handle function. So onclick handle is executed.